# Regex to avoid "dirty" web links

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess

If this is my actual URL to a file:

> http://www.example.org/posts.php?post=example-post-name

In my .htaccess file, how can I use a regular expression to get to this path when a user submits:

> http://www.example.org/posts/example-post-name

So far I've come up with this bringing together a few examples (this also included a www redirect):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z])/$ /posts.php?post=$1
```

But I'm not having much luck with it, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `+` after your `A-Za-z` group to indicate one or more characters, and also you need to add a `-` to the end of that group.  At the end, the `/?` indicates that the final slash may or may not be present.

Finally, add `[L]` to be sure no further rewrite rules get processed.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# First rewrite the posts:
RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ /posts.php?post=$1 [L]

# ing0 edit: add in dirs that need changing back.
# (I dont know if there is an easier way to do this).
RewriteRule ^posts/css/(.*)$ /css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^posts/img/(.*)$ /img/$1 [L]
# etc

# Then, if it's not a real file and doesn't already end in .php
# Note change here ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# redirect it to PHP.
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: If I add this I get a `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: !ing0 Please look in your server error log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Just looking for the logs on this server. If I put the regex to add .php to the end of the file (`RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]`) after your regex I get a 500 server errro. If I put it before, the website loads but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ing0 See my change above. You're probably going into an infinite redirect loop with your last rule to add .php.  I changed a `RewriteCond` so it doesn't rewrite requests that already end in `.php`.

Comment: Ah that made it work. Thanks. I've just edited your answer with a rewrite for dir that contain css or image directories.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to match the whole url and the regex wasn't quite right. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/posts/([\w-]+)$ $1/posts.php?post=$2
```

If it works only matching the non-base part of the url, this this:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([\w-]+)$ posts.php?post=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)/$ posts.php?post=$1
```